# Store_result and get_result for statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I use statements in PHP with mysqli library, before I fetch and bind_results I call the store_result.
After I've seen the mysqli_result class with methods like fetchArray/object etc.
So if I want use it, I call from mysqli_stmt object the method get_results... but if I call before the method store_result it give me an error of "non object" (get_result return false).
Es:

```
$s = $stmt->get_result(); //this work
```

but if I do

```
$stmt->store_result();
$s = $stmt->get_result(); //this not work, return false
```

So I'm trying to understand when I need to user store_result or get_result (and what is the right way) but in Mysql and php doc I didn't find nothing of useful.

PS: Can you explain why I should use the first or the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get_result whenever possible and store_result elsewhere.

Comment: Can you explain why I should use the first or the second? Thank you

Comment: Do you understand what does get_result do?

Comment: get_result return the mysqli_result object. I can use it to do fetchArray or other method for the result.
What I don't undestrand is if it is a good pratice to use get_result's mothods or use store_result and define by myself methods like fetchArray.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: Yes. Frankly, get_result makes mysqli prepared statements at least usable. So, thee is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: there could be only one issue with _very_ large result sets. In such a case, it would be better to avoid *both* get_result and store_result, to avoid sending all the result data from mysq to PHP at once, making its memory overloaded. However, for the regular web-serving PHP page it doesn't matter at all

Comment: @YourCommonSense, could you please explain what is a better alternative than `get_result` or `store_result` in the event that it is a *very* large result set?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII the only alternative is bind_result